# Display class object in GridView

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have such a situaton, that I am reading txt file making some operation on the lines and at the end I want to display everything in gridview. I have 3 separated columns. In first and second one I am displaying normal string values. But in middle one I have object returned by one class and I would like to display it normally in my gridview. How can I achieve it? I have something like this so far.

```
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] lines = line.Split(",".ToCharArray());
    object returnValue;

    MyColumns object = new MyColumns();
    object.Time = line[0];
    object.System_Description = line[1];
    object.User_Description = line[2];

    ///earlier in my code I have object of class called method
    returnValue = method.MyMethod(mc.System_Description);

    Class main = new Class();
    main.Data1= object.Time;
    main.ProblemData= returnValue;
    main.Data2= object.User_Description;
    list3.Add(main);
}

this.dataGridView3.DataSource = list3;
```

I have problem with showing ProblemData. Now in this column gridview shows me "project_name.Class_Name" (name of the class that this value was retured by)

EDIT:
Ok, I also have to mention that this class, from which returnValue gets values has 5 properties, let's say Categry, Name, Second_Name, Status and Value. This returnValue holds all this 5 properties with their current values.

EDIT2: Maybe someone knows how to display all this fields in one column? How can I join them only for displaying purpose? When I make normal List and insert this returnValue, it creates these 5 columns and insert values inside. Maybe it will make it easier to understand.

Comment: What is the returnValue? Is it a value or another object? If it is an object, then GridView cannot do a cascade. You will have to use nested GridViews.

Comment: returnValue is a variable with type object. I thought I have to do this way to handle the return object of my MyMethod. Am I right, with this?

Comment: Which property of that object will bind to the GridView column?

Comment: What is the type of the `returnValue`? I can see you declare `returnValue` as `object` but it may not be the actual type of it?

Comment: It is object, because I return object from that class.

Comment: @user2592968 if the actual type of it is `Object` the gridview should show `System.Object` not `project_name.Class_Name` as you said.

Comment: I guess you are right, there is something wrong with type of it. I have to check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my first comment on your question.

You have to use a nested GridView inside your second column which will bind to the `returnValue`. This is because GridView cannot automatically cascade your object datasource. The inner binding needs to be done in the RowDataBound event of your main GridView. For this to work, you will have to re-organise / re-factor your code.

Alternatively, you can concatenate the properties of the `returnValue` if their string representations can work for your scenario.

**Edit**:

The OP is asking about *WinForms* `DataGridView` (not ASP.Net):

The WinForms DataGridView does not support nesting out-of-the-box. However, there are some templating workarounds which are complicated. You are looking for a simple solution. I found one which can serve your immediate needs.

Hook into the `CellFormatting` event.

```
if (e.value is YOUR_OBJECT_TYPE) {
    e.Value = (e.Value as YOUR_OBJECT_TYPE).YOUR_PROPERTY_NAME; 
}
```

For details please refer to this: [Binding to Nested Properties](http://madprops.org/blog/Binding-to-Nested-Properties)

Alternate option:

The alternate option of concatenating the properties of the `returnValue` as string, will also work.

```
main.ProblemData = "Cat: " + returnValue.Category + ", Name: " + returnValue.Name;
```

Comment: Ok, I have no idea about nested GridView, I will have to read about it. Why it can't be simpler solution...

Comment: Can I make nested gridview, if I am not using asp?

Comment: My bad! I simply overlooked the fact that you are talking about WinForms and not ASP.

Comment: @user2592968 updated the answer to help you on winforms. You can still concatenate properties as strings for the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

you should have defined your class variables like a propertiesbecause you are using them in databinding. like this..

```
public String Data1 {get;set;}
```

also make your list a ObservableCollection as it will notify the view whenever you change something in your list..

Comment: Time is not type, it is a field of my class, with type string. Sorry I didn't mention this before.

Comment: i have updated that..you just have to follow the concept i want to tell you..you can explore further..the basiscs of databindings..if it is not working..comment below..

Comment: you can make property of returnvalue too..like above..and make sure returnvalue and problemdata type are same

Comment: They are defined in this way, but in their class. Only ProblemData in defined with type object.

Comment: so just make it as property too..with return type of problemdata class..make sure ..your problemdata..class also has varibals as properties..

Answer (score 0):

Two options

Override `ToString()` method in your ProblemData type

```
public class ProblemData
{
    //whatever...
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.format("{0}", this.SomeObject); //set proper display
    }
}

public class YourClass()
{
    //...
    public ProblemData ProblemData{ get; set;}
}
```

Or you can set grid column formatter if object type can be formatted using string.Format

```
dataGridView3.Columns["ProblemData"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N"; 
//display string.Format({0:N}
```